# Read in multiple .csv files, transform them and save as new files in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, purrr, split-apply-combine

I have 90 .csv files in my working directory and each of them is a 90*90 matrix. The files don't have consistent names (here is a sample)

```
>list.files()
[1] "sub-001-SGU-cn.csv" 
[2] "sub-001-SGU-nv.csv" 
[3] "sub-002-Cam-cn.csv" 
[4] "sub-002-Man-lv.csv"
[5] "sub-002-SGU-cn.csv"
```

Each matrix is asymmetric (i.e., only upper triangle contains values and lower triangle contains zeros). I want to write a loop function to read each file in, conduct a `log10` transformation of the upper triangle, and save the output in my working directory with the same name but adding in the suffix "_log.csv". How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

We may read the `.csv` files in to a `list` with `read.csv`, transform the data within the `list`, and then write it back to the same directory after appending `_log`

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
new_names <- sub(files, "\\.csv$", "_log.csv", files)
lst1 <- lapply(files, function(x) {
              dat <- read.csv(files)
              dat[upper.tri(dat)] <- log10(dat[upper.tri(dat)])
              dat
     })
Map(function(x, y) write.csv(x, file = y, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE),
      lst1, new_names)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
walk(files, ~ {
        dat <- read_csv(.x)
         dat[upper.tri(dat)] <- log10(dat[upper.tri(dat)])
       write_csv(dat, file = str_replace(.x, "\\.csv$", "_log.csv"))
   })
```

Comment: When I used your tidyverse code I got this error:

{-- Column specification -------------------------------------------------------------------------
Delimiter: ","
chr (1): 44832 5545 25971 1425 78 1 34228 945 123 6 13545 347 10927 129 289 7 8183 427 16489 ...

i Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
i Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
Error:
! Subscript `upper.tri(dat)` is a matrix, the data `log10(dat[upper.tri(dat)])` must have size 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
}

Comment: Is the error based on first solution or second?

Comment: The second. 

When I run the first solution, I also get an error:
`Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument`
`Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : object 'lst1' not found`

Comment: @Sid0311 In the solution, provided, i did create a list, if you check it `lst1 <- lapply(..`

Comment: @Sid0311 Do you get an error with `lst1 <- lapply(files, function(x) {
              dat <- read.csv(files);
              dat[upper.tri(dat)] <- log10(dat[upper.tri(dat)]);
              dat
     })`

Comment: If your filenames are correct, it should work correctly i.e. `dat <- mtcars[1:6, 1:6];
dat[upper.tri(dat)] <- log10(dat[upper.tri(dat)]);dat;`

Comment: for the `lst1<-lapply...` command, I get: `Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument`. I checked the file names - they all seem fine.

Comment: @Sid0311 sorry, I can't reproduce the issue.  You may need to update your post with a small reproducible example that shows the issue

Comment: I went with your second solution and figured out the issue: (1) in read.csv(...) sep="" was required; (2) data had to be saved as.data.frame and as numeric values; (3) log transformation was turning some values to infinity. It works perfectly now. Thanks @akrun!!